# Problem about parallelogram

Tags: geometry

In the diagram, $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. The points $E$ and $F$ are the midpoints of $BC$ and $AD$ respectively. The lines $DE$ and $BF$ intersect the diagonal $AC$ at $Q$ and $P$ respectively. Prove that

1. $DE$ is parallel to $FB$,
2. $AP = PQ = QC$

I know that $AD = CB$, and $FE$ is necessarily parallel to $DC$ and $AB$. But how do I continue from there?

[image]

Comment: Hint for part a): Prove DBEF is a parallelogram. Hint for part b): Use a) and intercept theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $FE \parallel AB \parallel CD$, we have that: $\angle BFE = \angle FBA = \angle EDC = \angle DEF$. That proves that $DE \parallel BF$.

Now from Intercept Theorem, as $FB \parallel DE$ that $\frac{PA}{PQ} = \frac{AF}{FD} = 1$ and similarly $\frac{CQ}{PQ} = \frac{CE}{EB} = 1$. Therefore $AP = PQ = CQ$